# How can I replace Zeep's default boolean serializer?

Tags: python, zeep

When I serialize a boolean value Zeep returns `"true"`/`"false"` (as per the `xsd.types.Boolean` class).

I would like to change this to return `"1"`/`"0"` instead because the API I'm working with only accepts these values.

How can I replace the default boolean serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up monkey patching the `xmlvalue` function.

```
class MyBoolean(Boolean):
    @check_no_collection
    def xmlvalue(self, value):
        return "1" if value and value not in ("false", "0") else "0"

Boolean.xmlvalue = MyBoolean.xmlvalue
```